How to use a prefab gameobject clone (Character Selection) as a player's target for a Navmesh Agent? How Navmesh Agent keep following the player
I'm new to Unity. I also new to Stackoverflow. Nice to meet you all!
I am using Unity version 2021.3 LTS
Here the details of my problem :

I still haven't found how to make navmesh agent to detect and follow a prefab clone.
So I'm using Character Selection Scene and then spawned into Scene Game.
I wanted an animal to follow our chosen character once it was loaded into the scene (for testing)
The animal is not following again when player move around

What did I try:

I have read some videos/articles/thread that I found. So I used method which the tag ("Player") and I used NavMesh Agent on the Animal. Also I put the tag for all characters
At first I thought the animal success followed the player, but it seems stopped at the position where the player spawned. The animal is not following again when player moving

What were I expecting :
*How can we make the animal keep following player that a clone?*
I'm using debug.log for targetPlayer.name. It identified my selected character's name that spawned at scene Game.
Here my Code
NPC_Follow.cs , I attached it on the animal
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
 
public class NPC_Follow : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    private GameObject targetPlayer;
 
    NavMeshAgent myAgent;
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        targetPlayer = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
 
        Debug.Log("Name: " + targetPlayer.name);
 
        myAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        myAgent.destination = targetPlayer.transform.position;
    }
}

I also put LoadCharacter.cs if needed to see.
LoadCharacter.cs, attached to empty gameobject at game scene. for spawning the selected character
public class LoadCharacter : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    public GameObject[] characterPrefabs;
    public Transform playerStartPosition;
    private string selectedCharacterDataName = "SelectedCharacter";
    int selectedCharacter;
    public GameObject playerObject;
 
 
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        selectedCharacter = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(selectedCharacterDataName, 0);
        playerObject = Instantiate(characterPrefabs[selectedCharacter],
                                 playerStartPosition.position,
                                 characterPrefabs[selectedCharacter].transform.rotation);
    }
}

Thank you and have a nice day!

OK, so, the short answer is, navmesh agents go to a "target" the target can be anything, but what it doesnt do is auto follow, so if Im at 10,10, and move to 11,11 the navmesh agent has to be told ive moved.

Hi,
I see, but I used the tag ("Player"). I also set it to void Update, so it keeps updating the player's position a.k.a auto follow, right?
Thank you

So you need to debug a little, other than you arguably should be doing "SetDestination" as the answer below, for many of us this kinda code works fine, so if its not working.. the question is why not.    One guess could be that your NPC_Follow code is running before you instantiate the player, so is null, but you'd have messages - now, you havent shared anything other than "not working" .. so, throw some debugs in, see whats going on, id also say potentially you dont need to update destination 600 times a second, you could do say 4 or 5..

To answer my question, I found solution
Debugging :

When I tested using Debug.Log Destination to that targetPlayer position. it remain same. even after the player moves.

What I did thinking :

it is because Empty GameObject parent that have child gameobject contain actual player?
because the debug.log destination position is same as Empty Parent's position. that Empty Parent also have tag "Player"

What I did:

reference to that child gameobject instead, rather than tag "player". since that child have actual player. It's success following!

Transform childTransform = playerCharacter.transform.Find("Player Name");
I will test later if I could try change tag EmptyGameObject Parent to none or any. so it could try searching where child gameobject that have tag "player"

I believe the problem is in the Update() function. Instead of using:
myAgent.destination = targetPlayer.transform.position;

You should use:
myAgent.SetDestination(targetPlayer.transform.position);

This ensures the pathfinding is properly initiated. I may be wrong though... Hope this helps.

Hi Ted,
I've tried your code. It still doesn't follow the player.
But thank you for answering, Ted! appreciated it!

Oh, Alright. Sorry I couldn't help. I am new to NavMesh myself.
